# Pass Location between two intents on different mobiles

Tags: android

If android having this two  activities  want to path data of current location from first activity to other what if both in same package but run in different mobile?  Each mobile is open and intent so I want to pass the data ( location ) of first mobile to the second one, how could the second mobile take this location where it will appear?

**First activity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(yarab.this, ghost .class);
i.putExtra("latitude", loc.getLatitude());
i.putExtra("longitude", loc.getLongitude());
startActivity(i);
```

**Second Activity**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
double latitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");
double longitude = extras.getDouble("longitude");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, whenever you use startActivity() or other means to start an activity, it always starts the activity in the same VM. So you can't just send the command to start an activity in other VM directly. To send the data from a device to other you can use Bluetooth API.

Comment: If they're close enough to use Bluetooth, they're probably close enough that sharing location is rather pointless, no? ;)

Comment: But the point is you can't invoke the activities to other device, just use any other means to pass data.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use some sort of API to handle communicating the data from one device to the other.  Each device would send a message to the API, which then knows to transmit that data to some other device.

Using [Google Apps Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) and/or [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) would probably be two good places to start.